# Is there in babel a list of all languages with RTL script supported by the package

Tags: babel, right-to-left

I searched in [babel manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf)  for a list of all languages with RTL script supported by the package and I found only two macros `bbl@alscripts` and `bbl@rscripts`  which are defined as follows:

```
\def\bbl@alscripts{,Arabic,Syriac,Thaana,}
\def\bbl@rscripts{% TODO. Base on codes ??
,Imperial Aramaic,Avestan,Cypriot,Hatran,Hebrew,
Old Hungarian,Old Hungarian,Lydian,Mandaean,Manichaean,%
Manichaean,Meroitic Cursive,Meroitic,Old North Arabian,
Nabataean,N'Ko,Orkhon,Palmyrene,Inscriptional Pahlavi,%
Psalter Pahlavi,Phoenician,Inscriptional Parthian,Samaritan,%
Old South Arabian,}
```

It appears from the two lists that they do not include some languages such as persian or urdu, is there an explanation for this and the difference between languages in alscript and languages in rscript.

Comment: Persian (Farsi) and Urdu are mentioned in the manual of `babel`. I suppose that they are supported. If we thing Arabic and Hebrew which are supported then we have at least four LTR supported languages. I never used these languages so it's just a conjecture please check it!

Comment: @miltos This is what is confusing here. The two languages are supported by the package but are not defined in the two lists!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are scripts, not languages. The Arabic script is used by many languages, and the pair script-language, which OpenType calls ‘language system’, is what counts in a locale. The languages with locale files are:

- **Arabic**: Arabic (several regions), Central Kurdish, Kashmiri,    Mazanderani, Northern Kurdish, Northern Luri, Pashto, Persian, Punjabi, Urdu, Uyghur, Uzbek.
- **Hebrew**: Hebrew, Yiddish.
- **Syriac**: Syriac

There are more locale files with RTL scripts in the GitHub repository. See for example https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/176 (for Phoenician).

As to the differences between `\bbl@rscripts` and `\bbl@alscripts`, it’s a technicality of the Unicode bidi algorithm, that’s all. Here is a thorough explanation, but it’s not for the faint of heart: https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/.

**Update Dec. 2023**

Also, with various levels of coverage:

- **Arabic**: Baluchi, Egyptian Arabic (aka Masri), Saraiki, Sindhi.
- **Avestan**: Avestan.
- **Hebrew**: Ladino.
- **Imperial Aramaic, Palmyrene, Nabataean**: Aramaic.
- **Mandaean**: Classical Mandaic.
- **Phoenician**: Phoenician.
- **Samaritan**: Samaritan.
- **Thaana**: Divehi.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.